# get actual table size not toast

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Using postgres....first off am I correct in saying 'toast table size' is the size assigned to the table? and 'table size' is the actual size of the data in the table.

I created a new table, which as of yet has no data in it, its table size is 0 bytes but its toast table size is 8192 bytes.

My Question being:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('zlimitreacjed_1'));
```

returns the toast size of the table '8192 bytes' what is the query for returning the actual size of the data in the table?

Comment: `8K`, which is default, for first page. Looks ok.

Comment: what? im asking why does pg_table_size return the toast table size and not the actual table size of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOAST data in Postgres relates to values that have been stored outside of the main table file, typically because they're quite large.  In terms of "the actual size of data in the table" the TOAST numbers have to be included because they *are* data in the table.

pg_table_size reports the size on disk of the table.  This is completely different to the size of the live data in the table.   There are a number of reasons for this, including:

- Space from deleted rows
- Old versions of rows left after updates
- pointers (used where the actual data has been stored in a toast file instead of the main file)
- free space map
- page header information
- row header information

For more details of the format of files check out http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage.html

If you're interested in how big the actual data is, you'd really have to select each record and add together the lengths of the all non-null fields in those rows.

You can do a VACUUM FULL which will clear out some of the non-data space (related to deleted rows etc.) but the storage overheads will still be there.

Comment: If you want the size for just the heap, use pg_relation_size().

Comment: @Jim Nasby You still need to deal with the data that is stored in toast and the free space in the heap